# Assign event handler to each button in a for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to assign an onclick attribute to each button generated through a for loop, without success.  The loop generates a table that is populated with search results and the button has to pass a value to JPlayer.  The following code, using the class of the button + i plain doesn't work, although I'm not sure why.  Removing the i variable will obviously just assign the event handler to the last element in the array, which indeed it does.  I've looked through a few similar questions here, as I gather this is a common pitfall with JS loops, but I can't make any of the answers work for this situation.

```
function displayResults(searchData){

    var numResults = searchData.results.length;

    $("#searchResults").html("");

    var table = document.createElement("table");
    table.setAttribute("class", "table");


    for(var i = 0;i < numResults; i++) {
        var resultTr = document.createElement("tr");
        var results = searchData.results[i];

        var resultArtist = document.createElement("td");
        resultArtist.appendChild(document.createTextNode(results.artist));
        var resultSong = document.createElement("td");
        resultSong.appendChild(document.createTextNode(results.songTitle));
        var resultAlbum = document.createElement("td");
        resultAlbum.appendChild(document.createTextNode(results.album));
        var resultDisk = document.createElement("button");      
        resultDisk.setAttribute("class", "playButton" +i);      

         $( ".playButton" +i).on( "click", { value: results.diskLocation }, function( event ) {

                player(event.data.value);
              });

        resultDisk.appendChild(document.createTextNode("play"));

        resultTr.appendChild(resultArtist);
        resultTr.appendChild(resultSong);
        resultTr.appendChild(resultAlbum);
        resultTr.appendChild(resultDisk);
        table.appendChild(resultTr);
        $("#searchResults").append(table);
    }
}
```

I've tried using `this`, but I cannot seem to make that work either.  So, how does one correctly assign event handlers to dynamically-produced elements in a loop?

Comment: Why aren't you using event delegation? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: Why are you mixing plain Javascript and jQuery like that? It's easier to read if you're consistent.

Comment: @Barmar I'm sure it's a horrible mix, but I seldom go anywhere near client-side programming so my skills are basic at best.   Point taken however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `$( ".playButton" +i)` the selector before you've added the new button to the DOM, so it's not finding anything. Change it to:

```
$(resultDisk).on("click", { value: results.disklocation }, function(event) {
    player(event.data.value);
});
```

Also, `$("#earchResults").append(table)` should be outside the `for` loop. You only have to append the table once, after it's completely filled in by the loop.